# Prob. 12, Sec. 5.2, in Bartle & Sherbert's INTRO TO REAL ANALYSIS: Continuity of additive functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, solution-verification

Here is Prob. 12, Sec. 5.2, in the book [*Introduction To Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition](https://sciencemathematicseducation.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/0471433314realanalysis4.pdf):

> A function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be **additive** if $f(x+y)= f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x, y$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $f$ is continuous at some point $x_0$, then it is continuous at every point of $\mathbb{R}$.

My Attempt:

> Let $c$ be an arbitrary real number.
>
> First suppose that $x_0 = 0$. As $f$ is continuous at the point $0$, so given any real number $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$\lvert f(x) \rvert = \lvert f(x) - 0 \rvert = \lvert f(x) - f(0) \rvert < \varepsilon $$
>   for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which 
>   $$ \lvert x  \rvert  = \lvert x-0 \rvert < \delta. $$
>   Then 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - f(c) \rvert =  \lvert f( x - c ) \rvert < \varepsilon $$
>   for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
>   $$ \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta. $$
>   Thus it follows that $f$ is continuous at every point $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Am I right?

> Now let us suppose that $x_0 \neq 0$. As $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, so, for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$ \left\lvert f \left(x - x_0 \right) \right\rvert = \left\lvert f(x) - f \left( x_0 \right) \right\rvert < 
> \varepsilon $$
>   for all real numbers $x$ which satisfy 
>   $$ \left\lvert x- x_0 \right\rvert < \delta. $$
>
> Now if we could show from here that $f$ is continuous at $0$, then as before we will have managed to show that $f$ is continuous at every real number $c$.

What next? How to proceed from here to show that our function $f$ is continuous at $0$? Or, is there any other route?

Comment: Would you agree that a systematic call to check your work is associated much more closely with "seeking personal advice" rather than just asking mathematical questions?

Comment: @uniquesolution I'm sorry but do you disapprove of my asking questions in the manner I do? What if I arrive at a wrong conclusion during the steps of my proof? Hence my asking "Am I right?"!

Comment: I appreciate your keen efforts to study mathematics. I do think however that it takes some non-trivial presumptuousness to bombard this site with requests to practically tutor your self-study. I think that this site is not the place for that, and that's why I think such posts as yours ought to be closed on the grounds that they seek personal advice.

Comment: Everything in the second yellow box has pretty much nothing to do about what you're asked to prove. If I were you I'd remove it to make the relevant part more directly accessible.

Comment: @uniquesolution asking to check one’s work does not come under “seeking personal advice”. There is even a tag called [tag:proof-verification] for the same.

Comment: @uniquesolution that is pretty clearly not the intended use of the seeking personal advice close button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Let $| t-0 | = |t| < \delta$, where $\delta$ is the one you have in the second box. Then $t + x_0 = x\in \mathbb{R}$, so $|t| = |x - x_0| < \delta$.

Thus, $|f(t) - f(0)| = |f(t)| = |f(x-x_0)| = |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ for $|t| < \delta$.

So $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Why does the continuity at 0 implies continuity at every real number? Sorry for resurrecting the question.

Comment: @belwarDissengulp this is proven in the original question under the box "My Attempt:", the proof seems correct to me.